# Downloading a file from the server using Symfony 3

Tags: symfony, download, http-status-code-404

I'm having error 404 when I try to get a file from the server. The folder I have is inside the folder / web /, but when I click on the link https: // my_site_name / web / my_folder_file, error 404 appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the server already points to the `web` directory, so if you have a file in `web/folder/my_file.txt` you can access it with `folder/my_file.txt`

Comment: Sounds like you've configured Apache incorrectly for the wrong folder.